# A Two-Die Puzzle

Tags: probability

So, I was bored at one point and decided to think about random events and probability, and I came up with this:

> There are two dice, and one of them is loaded. You do not know which one is loaded, and each die has a theoretical 50/50 chance to become loaded. Both dice look, feel and weigh the same, and are indistinguishable from each other. However, the way the die rigs itself is that when the other die (the non-loaded one) rolls a certain number, which is random, it always rolls the rigged number, which is also random. For clarification, all random values are predetermined before the rolling process begins, and they can't change, ever. The question is, what is the average number of roll necessary to have at least a 90% or more certainty to know the following: which die is rigged, which number is it rigged to, and which number does the other, non-rigged, die need to roll for the rigged die to land on the number it is rigged to.

As a side note, you can call die 1 'A' and die 2 'B'. Have fun!
Also, added explanation.

> I can see that many are getting confused by the wording. I can explain “ the way the die rigs itself is that when the other die (the non-loaded one) rolls a certain number, which is random, it always rolls the rigged number, which is also random.”. So, say that dice 1 (a) is rigged to the number 2, and that the other dice (b)needs to roll a 1 for it to rig. If dice b roll a 1, dice a will ALWAYS roll a 2. If dice b doesn’t roll a 1, dice a still has a 1/6 chance of rolling a 2, but it isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: If I have understood the rules correctly (not sure about that) then the unfair die will not show uniform statistics.  That is, it will show one value with probability $\frac 56\times \frac 16+\frac 16\times 1= \frac {11}{36}$ and the others with probability $\frac 5{36}$.  And, of course, there will be some value $i$ such that $(j,i)$ occurs but $(i,j)$ does not (where $j$ denotes any value other than $i$).

Comment: I don't think the question is answerable without a qualification like "What is the average number of rolls necessary to determine *with 99% certainty* that..." Otherwise, you could just be unlucky and roll $(1,1)$ for the rest of your life, as unlikely as that would be.

Comment: Could you clarify on an example "the way the die rigs itself is that when the other die (the non-loaded one) rolls a certain number, which is random, it always rolls the rigged number, which is also random."?

Comment: I can see that many are getting confused by the wording. I can explain “ the way the die rigs itself is that when the other die (the non-loaded one) rolls a certain number, which is random, it always rolls the rigged number, which is also random.”. So, say that dice 1 (a) is rigged to the number 2, and that the other dice (b)needs to roll a 1 for it to rig. If dice b roll a 1, dice a will ALWAYS roll a 2. If dice b doesn’t roll a 1, dice a still has a 1/6 chance of rolling a 2, but it isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: I think you should add this explanation in the question.